# How do I nest a div inside an anchor tag in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I'm a bit of a Ruby on Rails amateur, and I am trying to nest a div tag inside of an anchor tag in rails. I can make it work, but the resulting code I have written is terrible and is certainly NOT the rails way.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish in HTML:

```
<a href="tell-a-friend">
<div id="tellafriend">
    <strong>Strength in Numbers.</strong><br />
    Suggest a friend or colleague to participate in this survey.
</div>
</a>
```

Here is what I came up with to do it in ERB:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:div, 
    content_tag(:strong, 'Add your labor rates now.') + 
    content_tag(:br, '') + ' We are counting on you.', :id => 'participate'), 
participate_path %>
```

Or here I mixed some HTML and ERB:

```
<%= link_to '<div id="results">
    <strong>See the results.</strong><br />
    Knowledge is power.
</div>'.html_safe, results_path %>
```

Both of my solutions seem very ugly... but moving it into a helper didn't seem like the right thing to do, given that the content of the DIV changes and that I am only displaying 3 of these on one page.

So if anyone is aware of a better way to do this, I am interested! Any combination of HTML, ERB and HAML is ok by me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Links work as blocks:

```
<% link_to '', my_path do %>
  <div></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't know that. /cry

Update:
Just tested it in my rails3 beta4 app... needed a minor tweak to make it work. Essentially <% link_to my_path do %> ... <% end %>

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. The '' part of the link_to shouldn't be there at all in a block. And Rails 3 may use <%= instead of <% in opening line.

Answer (score 1):

**FYI:** An ANCHOR surrounding a DIV is not legal in HTML 4.01 Transitional (but it is in HTML5?) so make sure that you use the correct doc-type and test on the target browser(s)!

```
<head>
<title>a</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a href="www.google.com">
<div>test</div>
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can run this at [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and change the DOCTYPE to see for which mode(s) this is valid. (Make sure to specify the encoding as well to get rid of the warning :-)

Comment: Interesting, but this is a rails specific question.

Comment: You could also just put an empty anchor tag in front of the div.

Answer (score 0):

The worst is :

```
<%= link_to(url, html_options = {}) do %>
   # name
<% end %>
```